# How to access image data stored in VC++ BSTR

Tags: c#, c++11

I have a C# app from which I make a request to a COM based dll for an image and the image is returned in string to the C# app.

Actually in the COM dll it returns the binary information in a BSTR. How to store this into a BMP?

I tried `System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(string)` But did had distorted image.

Comment: Where does C++ come into this?

Comment: the COM dll is built on VC++ that's why I mentioned C++. Sorry for not making clear

Answer (score 0):

BSTR data is actually in UCS-2 format, not UTF8, so you may want to try this with the Unicode encoding instead of UTF8. In .NET, the Unicode encoding actually means UTF16, but that is the same as UCS-2 except for character encodings that need more than 16 bits.

This still might not work, of course, depending on exactly how the COM dll actually encodes the image data.

Comment: I tried System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes() to get UTF16 but did not work. In VB6.0 if I try to access the same image information from the COM dll. All I need to do is just access this BSTR value and write it into a file. It works perfectly fine. Please guide me more what I can do.